# Указатель this. Как передать объект в качестве параметра?

Tags: java

```
я понял что ошибка в методе ToString. Именно при рекурсивном выводе строка обновляется, как мне ее исправить?

public class Node {
        int x;
        Node l, r;
        public Node() {}
        public Node(int x){
            this.x = x;
        }
        public void add(int x){ //Добавление элемента в дерево
            if(this == null){ // ТУТ ОШИБКА
                this.x = x; // Если дерево пусто то создаем его
            }
            if(x < this.x){ // Если добавляемое значение меньше значения узла
                if(l != null) l.add(x); // Если узел не пуст вызываем рекурсивно
                else{
                    l = new Node(x); // Если нашли пустое место создаем узел
                }
            }
            if(x > this.x){ // Если добавляемое значение больше значения узла
                if(r != null) r.add(x);// Если узел не пуст вызываем рекурсивно
                else{
                    r = new Node(x); // Если нашли пустое место создаем узел
                }
            }
        }
        public String toString() {
            String s= null;
            if(this != null) { // ТУТ ОШИБКА
                l.toString();
                s += this.x + " ";
                r.toString();
            }
            return s;
        }
    }
```

Мэйн

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Random r = new Random();
    Node Tree = new Node();
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        Tree.add(r.nextInt(100));
    }
    System.out.println(Tree.toString());
}
```

подскажите пожалуйста
выкидывает ошибку

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at Node.toString(Node.java:31)
    at Start.main(Start.java:13)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)
```

Comment: `this` разве может быть `null`?  Сдаётся этот вывод об ошибке не соответствует приведённому исходному коду. Может что-то там не откомпилировалось и работает совсем другая версия? Ошибка должна быть на строке `s += this.x...` потому что s = null в самом начале и до того как не меняется. Или просто кто-то не умеет считать строки?

Comment: Что-то я не понял вообще сути проверок `this == null`, внутри нестатического метода `this` по определению не может быть `null` (а внутри статического компилятор не позволит вам обращаться к `this` в таком контексте). Вы понимаете, что `this` - это ссылка на текущий экземпляр класса (когда вы работаете внутри нестатических методов класса, то вы по определению работаете с определенным экземпляром класса)?

Comment: Так стектрейс говорит, что ошибка в _Node.toString(Node.java:31)_ и вполне возможно, что этот метод вызывается **до** того момента, как инициализируются вершины `l`,`r`

Comment: Добавьте код метода `main`

Comment: @Grundy он неизбежно вызывается до того момента, т.к. в дереве всегда есть листья, а метод рекурсивно до них дойдет.

Comment: public static void main(String[] args) {
        Random r = new Random();
        Node Tree = new Node();
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            Tree.add(r.nextInt(100));
        }
        System.out.println(Tree.toString());
    }

Comment: @Артем добавляйте код в вопрос (посредством _"править"_), а не в комментарии.

Answer (score 4):

Основная ошибка в том, что вы проверяете `this`, который не может быть `null`, а поля класса

```
Node l, r;
```

Которые не инициализированы, не проверяете.

```
public String toString() {
    String s= "";
    if(l != null) { // ТУТ ОШИБКА
        s = l.toString();
    }
    s += this.x + " ";
    if(r != null){
        s += r.toString();
    }
    return s;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
public String toString() {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    if (l != null) { // ТУТ ОШИБКА
        sb.append(l).append(" ");
    }
    sb.append(this.x);
    if (r != null) {
        sb.append(" ").append(r);
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```